# How to detect user have select GPS-provided time as their source of automatic time

Tags: settings, gps, date-and-time

I need to identify whether the device use GPS-provided time. I have went though documentation on [Settings.Global](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global). My question is how to get to know whether the user select network-provided time or GPS-provided time as their source of time. Can I differentiate the two sources from `AUTO_TIME` parameter?

Sample code below will return `true` if user choose network-provided time.

```
(Settings.Global.getInt(this.applicationContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 0) == 1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange, a Q&A focusing on Android end-users solving their issues. Considering the scope of this site, the community may provide answers to achieve this either by ADB/shell command or apps, or by technical explanation, but please note that the coding solution is out of scope here.